# Goodwillie-entire functors

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory

Let $F : \mathsf{Spaces} \to \mathsf{Spaces}$ be a functor, and for $X \in \mathsf{Spaces}$, let $F_X : \mathsf{Spaces}_{/X} \to \mathsf{Spaces}_{/F(X)}$ denote the induced functor.

Recall that in [Goodwillie's calculus of functors](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Goodwillie+calculus), $F$ is said to be *$\rho$-analytic* at $X \in \mathsf{Spaces}$ if (roughly) for $\rho$-connected $Y \to X$, the canonical map $F_X(Y) \to TF_X(Y)$ is an equivalence, where $TF_X$ is the limit of the Taylor tower of $F_X$. For example, the identity functor is 1-analytic at $\ast \in \mathsf{Spaces}$.

**Definition:** A functor $F : \mathsf{Spaces} \to \mathsf{Spaces}$ is *entire* if, for every $X \in \mathsf{Spaces}$, there exists $\rho \in \mathbb N$ such that $F$ is $\rho$-analytic at $X$.

For example, $n$-excisive functors are $(-2)$-analytic everywhere, and thus entire. Limits of $n$-excisive functors (where $n$ may vary over the limit diagram) are likewise entire.

**Question 1:** Is the identity functor entire? How about $\Omega^\infty \Sigma^\infty_+$?

**Question 2:** Are there other naturally-occurring examples of entire functors?

**Question 3:** Is every entire functor a limit of $n$-excisive functors (where $n$ is allowed to vary)?

**Question 4:** What does the theory of analytic continuation look like? For instance, if $F$ is not entire, can be this detected in the form of some kind of "singularity" at the edge of some "radius of convergence"?

(Recall that we think of the collection of $n$-connected maps $Y \to X$ as forming a ball of radius $e^{-n}$ centered at $X$. So being $\rho$-analytic says something about the convergence of the Taylor tower on a ball of radius $e^{-\rho}$.)